# Can you pass an array from javascript to asp.net mvc controller action without using a form?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, arrays, binding

I know that if I have a form with multiple elements with the same name I can use this to bind to an array, but is there any way to pass an array from a javascript function to an ASP.NET MVC controller action without using a form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! Using XmlHttpRequests you can send HTTP GET or POST commands.

Lots of javascript libraries like jQuery make this very easy. For example in jQuery you could do it this way..

```
<input name="myField" value="1" />
<input name="myField" value="2" />
<input name="myField" value="3" />
<button id="send">Send data to server</button>
```

Here's the javascript code

```
$('#send').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var postParams = {
    myField : []
  };

  $("input[name='myField']").each(function() {
    postParams.myField.push($(this).val());
  });

  $.post("/controller/action", postParams);
  return false;
});
```

This should send a POST request with the following param:

```
myField=1,2,3
```

Comment: thanks, this worked but i had to add jquery.ajaxsettings.traditional to get the full end to end to work

Comment: @Ieora: Hi, what did your controller signature param look like?  method(string values) or method(string[] values)?

Comment: @JaJ, method(string values) is fine, but make sure to change postParams to values or you could use method(string postParams)

Comment: It should also be available in Request.QueryString object