# How to load a partialview with an int array use jquery in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I use this code to get checked date,but it's not get the int[] value. Where is wrong.

***View Page:***

```
        function displayCheckedPersons() {
        var $checkedRecords = new Array();
        var j;
        j = 0;
           var nodes = $("#PersonTree").jstree("get_checked",null,true); 
           $.each(nodes, function (i, element) {
               if ($(element).attr("ifPerson") == "Y") {
                   $checkedRecords[j] = $(element).attr("id");
                   j = j + 1;
               };
           });

       if ($checkedRecords.length < 1) {
            alert('Please Select Persons first.');
            return;
        }


        $('#result').load('<%= Url.Action("DisplayCheckedPersons", "Scheduling") %>',$checkedRecords);
    }
</script>
```

***Action Code:***

```
        public ActionResult DisplayCheckedPersons(int[] checkedRecords)
    {
        AttendMSDataContext db = new AttendMSDataContext();
        checkedRecords = checkedRecords ?? new int[] { };
        return PartialView("CheckedPersons", db.Persons.Where(o => checkedRecords.Contains(o.id)));
    }
```

Edit by dai:
I used $ajax to post the array,like this:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<%= Url.Action("DisplayCheckedPersons", "Scheduling") %>",
            data: { checkedRecords: checkedPersons },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (request) { $("#result").html(request); },
            traditional: true
        });
```

Comment: I'm don't think its the cause but you dont need to be using $ infront of checkedRecords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data needs to be used like this:

```
$('#result').load('<%= Url.Action("DisplayCheckedPersons", "Scheduling") %>', $checkedRecords);
```

Becomes:

```
$('#result').load('<%= Url.Action("DisplayCheckedPersons", "Scheduling") %>', { checkedRecords: $checkedRecords });
```

The syntax is:

```
{ expectedName: JavascriptVariable, expectedName2: JavascriptVariable2 }
```

**Edit:**

Here is an Ajax example showing how to load your content. The .load example from abouve should work im not sure whats going wrong for you but here you go:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: "<%= Url.Action("DisplayCheckedPersons", "Scheduling") %>",
    data: { checkedRecords: checkedPersons },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
            $("#YourDiv").html(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The JavascriptVariable is $checkedRecords ,if use :$('#result').load('<%= Url.Action("DisplayCheckedPersons", "Scheduling") %>',{checkedRecords: checkedRecords});Get a error :checkedRecords is not defined

Comment: Rename $checkedRecords to checkedRecords

Comment: Thanks for you help! But,the array values not passed to the function while renamed $checkedRecords to checkedPersons, the parameter int[] still null.I think the main problem is how to pass array values from javascript to asp.net mvc function by $.load().

Comment: @Steve, why add the $ back in its not really convention that was the whole point of removing it.

Comment: @dai, Have you checked firebug to see what data is being posted, if any?

Comment: I have checked the posted data by google chrome "Inspect element". An Array data have posted from the javascript code, array[3],0:"2",1:"3",2:"4",but in the asp.net mvc Action which being called the param (int[] checkedRecords) is null. I had used             $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<%= Url.Action("DisplayCheckedPersons", "Scheduling") %>",
    data: { checkedRecords: checkedPersons },
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    });   The Array data checkedPersons can posted to the param checkedRecords,but I need .load. How can i ? I need encode the array to a json data?

Comment: @Henry - I added the dollar back in purely so your example code matched the code in the question :)

Comment: @Steve,:)-,There are any solution for the question?

Comment: You could add a success handler - I'll update my main answer to reflect the changes you would need and see how it goes for you.

Comment: Dai, check my updated answer. Im not sure If I completely understand your problem with the .load I have shown you but try that.

Comment: When I add a success handler, I have another question "how to convert the data include a Grid View Control with script code to a html data. (.html(data)) is not the answer.

Comment: @dai.frank - [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673319/can-you-pass-an-array-from-javascript-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-action-without-us) demonstrates passing an array from javascript to an MVC action.

Comment: So is the data now being sent to your action correctly? Jquery automatically evaluates JavaScript so any scripts running will still be able to run. doing .html(data) is exactly what .load() does once complete so if its not working doing it this way, it wont work through load either.